# Cant move Div position without messing up a containing H2 position

Tags: html, css

i have a div which contains the users username. When the user hovers their mouse over, i have a panel that drops down. I cant position the div so that it fills the usernames box without messing up the H2 username.

In my css i have a H2 tag which needs to be there for other h2 text's on the website so i need the positioning to go in the user-name id to overwrite it. Overall i need it so the login-handler fills the box, the login panel appears at the bottom of the box, and the H2 is in center vertically and horizontally.

it seems simple but its just driving me crazy. Here is a jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/xksbr73u/1/

HTML

```
<div id = "user-container">
        <div class = "dropdown-login-handler">
                <h2 id = "user-name">
          Guest 1
                </h2>
            <div class = "dropdown-login-panel">
                    <div id = "login-screen">

                    </div>
                </div>
        </div >
</div>

<div id = "dont-push"></div>
```

CSS

```
    #user-container {
    width: 250px;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #5B3A23;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-login-handler {
    margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -12px;
}

.dropdown-login-panel {
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #5B3A23;
    position: relative;
    width: 248px;
    top: 23px;
    cursor: hand;
    z-index: 999;
    font-family: 'roadstar';
}
.dropdown-login-handler:hover .dropdown-login-panel {
    display: block;
}
#user-name {

}
#login-screen{
  height: 100px;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'roadstar';
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
#dont-push {
  background-color: green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

The end result i would like to look like this [image]

but also so the panel appears when the mouse enters anywhere in the box (the handler doesnt spill outside the box or isnt in some parts)

Comment: I can't really understand what the problem is. Can you update your fiddle so that the broken behavior is apparent?

Comment: Yes in the jsfiddle the text (h2) is not centered verticly, when i try to do this, i mess up the dropdown handler and drop down panel. I tried to make it position absolute which then messed up the positioning of everything

Comment: Can you create an image of your desired result, it's hard to picture what the end resut should be - this centres the h2: https://jsfiddle.net/xksbr73u/11/

Comment: yes i added a picture to the question but its also the poisitioning of the handler thats important, i cant show it because its transparent

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xksbr73u/12/ this is a little better as it sorts out the hover problem

Comment: thanks! i think the position of the panel being absolute might cause problems on the actual website but theres an answer of someone doing it with relative, thankyou though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a little too many unnecessary values set. Most of what I did was just cleaning up your margins and paddings. Then, I fit your `h2` to match the height of it's parent and cleaned up the margin.

```
#user-name {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m2q9bv45/

Comment: This is perfect, exacly what i wanted tyvm :)